# How old are Ishishi, Noshishi, and Zorori?

Tags: kaiketsu-zorori

I am mainly wondering about Zorori's age, I've seen a lot of the episodes and haven't found out yet. If you can, please give the episode number or the canon source that verifies your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the anime, Zorori age was never mentioned.

However, in the spin-off manga, despite his young appearance, Zorori's age is over 120 years.

- In the original manga series, ほうれんそうマン (*Hourensou Man*, Spinach Man), the 1st volume, titled へんし〜んほうれんそうマン (*Henshi~n Hourensou Man*, Transform Spinach Man) has a scene of Zorori's 100th birthday. (source: [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%BB%E3%81%86%E3%82%8C%E3%82%93%E3%81%9D%E3%81%86%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3)).
- On volume 15, titled かいけつゾロリつかまる！！ (*Kaiketsu Zorori Tsukamaru!!*, "Kaiketsu Zorori Arrested!!"), there's a newspaper about his fugitive warrant with the text 「かいけつゾロリ(109)」 (*Kaiketsu Zorori (109)*), which means that he was 109 years old at that time. (source: [hensachi60's tweet (Japanese)](https://twitter.com/hensachi60/status/601726597717069825))
- On volume 46, titled かいけつゾロリ きょうふのようかいえんそく (*Kaiketsu Zorori Kyōfu no Youkai Ensoku*, "Kaiketsu Zorori, the Terrifying Monster Field Trip"), it's mentioned that his age was 124 years old. (source: [Yahoo! Chiebukuro (Japanese)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1296896127))

The boar brothers Ishishi and Noshishi's ages, however, are never mentioned at all.

---

Reference:

- [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84%E3%81%91%E3%81%A4%E3%82%BE%E3%83%AD%E3%83%AA#.E7.99.BB.E5.A0.B4.E3.82.AD.E3.83.A3.E3.83.A9.E3.82.AF.E3.82.BF.E3.83.BC)
- [pixiv encyclopedia (Japanese)](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%82%BE%E3%83%AD%E3%83%AA)

Comment: Spinach Man is the original source for Zorori in which Zorori was a villain. Zorori's private exploits are actually the spinoff show. Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaiketsu

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I've updated the info.